Finding the 7th derivative at 0 using the Maclaurin series
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^3 e^{x^2}}{1 - x^2},\qquad f^{(7)}(0) = ?
$$
The Maclaurin series is given by:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} x^k = f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1!} x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!} x^2 + \dots + \frac{f^{(7)}(0)}{7!} x^7 + \cdots
$$
Here, $a_k$ is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion. Therefore:
$$
f^{(7)}(0) = 7! \cdot a_k.
$$
To find $a_k$, I decide to expand the components $e^{x^2}$ and $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ into their respective power series.

Update:
The power series expansions are:
$$
e^{x^2} = 1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^4),
$$
$$
\frac{1}{1 - x^2} = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + \mathcal{O}(x^4).
$$
Substituting these expansions into $f(x)$:
$$
f(x) = x^3 \left(1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^4)\right) \left(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)\right).
$$
Expanding step by step:
$$
f(x) = \left(x^3 + x^5 + \frac{1}{2}x^7 + \mathcal{O}(x^7)\right)\left(1 + x^2 + x^4 + \mathcal{O}(x^4)\right).
$$
Carrying out the multiplication:
$$
f(x) = x^3 + 2x^5 + \frac{5}{2}x^7
$$
Thus, the coefficient of $x^7$ is:$\frac{5}{2}.$
Finally, substituting into the formula for $f^{(7)}(0)$:
$$
f^{(7)}(0) = 7! \cdot \frac{5}{2}.
$$
Calculating step by step:
$$
f^{(7)}(0) = 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{5}{2} = 12,600.
$$
I hope I haven't made any mistakes.

What have you tried ? It can be done with the help of several techniques, but we cannot guess your "level" without giving context.

@Abezhiko I added my idea

Your idea works indeed (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product), you should give it a try.

@Abezhiko thanks , im following (and updating the post).

@Abezhiko I think I understood, finally. Thank you

We just need to find the coefficient of $x^7$ (say $a$) in the expansion of $f(x)$ and our answer will be $a×7!$
Using your idea, we get that $$f(x)=x^3\left(1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}\right)(1+x^2+x^4)$$
Here, I ignored the higher power terms as they all will be ultimately $0$.
So from here we get $a=\frac52$
Hence the answer is $$\boxed{7!×\frac52=12600}$$

Thanks for the reply! I updated the post. I haven't made any typing errors.

@mo-_- it's all correct
